# How to remove the deprecation warning in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'am using mongoose-ttl node package to clear the collections. But I'am getting this warning.

```
(node:4768) DeprecationWarning: collection.remove is deprecated. Use deleteOne, deleteMany, or bulkWrite instead.
```

I'am not using any methods like remove() etc.But I can't understand from where this warning is thrown.
Please suggest me any method to remove this warning.
TTL Code goes here:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var ttl = require('mongoose-ttl');

var OTPStore = new mongoose.Schema({
  OTPNo: {
    type: Number,
    require: true
  }
});
OTPStore.plugin(ttl, { ttl: '30m', interval: '30m'});
module.exports = mongoose.model("OTPStore", OTPStore);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you wanna delete something from db.

```
const store=await OTPStore.deleteOne({_id:id}) //this will find the first one  and delete

 const store=await OTPStore.deleteMany({ _id:id })
//this will delete all. This used for properties that some of the instances have others not. For example if you had "isExpensive" property in your schema you could pass {isExpensive:true} and mongose would find all the instances that meet this criteria and remove them 

const store=await OTPStore.findByIdAndRemove(id) 
// if you notice in above examples I passed an object. But here you are already notifying mongooose that you are querying by id, so just put an id as argument
```

NOTE that this operations are async operations so in order to use await, make sure wrapper function should start with `async function`